# How do I read a non standard csv file into dataframe with python or scala

Tags: python, scala, dataframe, rdd

I have a data set sampling below to be processed with python or scala:

```
FWD,13032009:09:01,10.56| FWD,13032009:10:53,11.23| FWD,13032009:15:40,23.20
SPOT,13032009:09:04,11.56| FWD,13032009:11:45,11.23| SPOT,13032009:12:30,23.20
FWD,13032009:08:01,10.56| SPOT,13032009:12:30,11.23| FWD,13032009:13:20,23.20| FWD,13032009:14:340,56.00
FWD,13032009:08:01,10.56| SPOT,13032009:12:30,11.23| FWD,13032009:13:20,23.20
```

Every line is to be split into multiple smaller string that can be further splitted.

What I am looking for is an efficient way to generate an RDD or Dataframe with content below:

```
FWD,13032009:09:01,10.56 
FWD,13032009:10:53,11.23
FWD,13032009:15:40,23.20
SPOT,13032009:09:04,11.56
FWD,13032009:11:45,11.23
SPOT,13032009:12:30,23.20
FWD,13032009:08:01,10.56
SPOT,13032009:12:30,11.23
FWD,13032009:13:20,23.20
FWD,13032009:14:340,56.00
FWD,13032009:08:01,10.56
SPOT,13032009:12:30,11.23
FWD,13032009:13:20,23.20
```

Note the more efficient the better as the total row count in production could be as large as million

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have are reading from a csv file, you can read each line to a list. Flatten the values and then process them as individual rows.

**Read file into a list** - 1 million rows should not be too much to handle:

```
import csv
import itertools

import pandas as pd

with open('test.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '|')
    rows = list(reader)
```

**Flatten and split from a single list** - the excellent `itertools` library from Python's standard library returns a generator which helps with memory and is efficient.

```
flat_rows = itertools.chain.from_iterable(rows)
list_rows = [i.strip().split(',') for i in flat_rows]
```

The nested list,`list_rows` now gives you a clean and formatted list which you can send to `pandas` if you want to create a `dataframe`.

```
list_rows
>>
[['FWD', '13032009:09:01', '10.56'],
 ['FWD', '13032009:10:53', '11.23'],
 ['FWD', '13032009:15:40', '23.20'],
 ['SPOT', '13032009:09:04', '11.56'],
 ['FWD', '13032009:11:45', '11.23'],
 ['SPOT', '13032009:12:30', '23.20'],
 ['FWD', '13032009:08:01', '10.56'],
 ['SPOT', '13032009:12:30', '11.23'],
 ['FWD', '13032009:13:20', '23.20'],
 ['FWD', '13032009:14:340', '56.00'],
 ['FWD', '13032009:08:01', '10.56'],
 ['SPOT', '13032009:12:30', '11.23'],
 ['FWD', '13032009:13:20', '23.20']]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bernard, how do I register the pandas df to a temptable like the regular df so that I can use sql to do the analytics?

Comment: @mdivk well, I would suggest that if you want to analyze it, and since it already sits in a dataframe, analyze with `pandas`. If you want to store it then look up `pd.DataFrame.to_sql`. If you have a new question, post a new question and will go from there, thanks!

Comment: Thank you Bernard, I just need to register the df into a temp table and then run ad-hoc sql query, can you please share here .... please.....

Comment: I tried `df.registerTempTable("test")` and it is not working in my python3 Jupyter notebook

Comment: You need to be clear on whether you are on `spark` rdd or `pandas` dataframe, they have different methods.

Comment: pandas provides better performance, that is what I want, thank you very much

Comment: or can you provide the code for generating a spark dataframe from the beginning? sorry and thank you for your patience

Comment: You can read more from some documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/spark-pandas.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206551/discussion-between-mdivk-and-bernardl).

Answer (score 0):

Python solution: If you get the text as a string, you can `replace()` your `|`  sequence with a newline (`\n`) and then read that as a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_set = """FWD,13032009:09:01,10.56| FWD,13032009:10:53,11.23| FWD,13032009:15:40,23.20
SPOT,13032009:09:04,11.56| FWD,13032009:11:45,11.23| SPOT,13032009:12:30,23.20
FWD,13032009:08:01,10.56| SPOT,13032009:12:30,11.23| FWD,13032009:13:20,23.20| FWD,13032009:14:340,56.00
FWD,13032009:08:01,10.56| SPOT,13032009:12:30,11.23| FWD,13032009:13:20,23.20
"""
data_set *= 100000  # Make it over a million elements to ensure performance is adequate
data_set = data_set.replace("| ", "\n")

data_set_stream = StringIO(data_set)  # Pandas needs to read a file-like object, so need to turn our string into a buffer
df = pd.read_csv(data_set_stream)
print(df)  # df is our desired DataFrame
```

Comment: Thank you Oliver, in a production we cannot generate a dataset your way, it would have to be reading from a file, the issue here is the file is not a standard csv because some lines contain different smaller csv section than others, in the sample data you can see the third line has 4 sections while the others have 3

Comment: Instead of your string being hardcoded (as in my example), you could simply read the file into the `data_set` variable: `with open("DATASET_FILENAME", "r") as my_file: data_set = my_file.read()`. Secondly, my example neatly handles different numbers of sections by separating any number of sections found to be concatenated (you can try my code and see that it correctly flattens the dataset).

Comment: Thanks Oliver, how do I register a pandas created dataframe as temptable? I want to run queries on the teamptable

Comment: If you would want to run a query, `pandas` has an api [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Scala way if you are interested,

`val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List("FWD,13032009:09:01,10.56| FWD,13032009:10:53,11.23| FWD,13032009:15:40,23.20", "SPOT,13032009:09:04,11.56| FWD,13032009:11:45,11.23| SPOT,13032009:12:30,23.20","FWD,13032009:08:01,10.56| SPOT,13032009:12:30,11.23| FWD,13032009:13:20,23.20| FWD,13032009:14:340,56.00","FWD,13032009:08:01,10.56| SPOT,13032009:12:30,11.23| FWD,13032009:13:20,23.20"))`

`val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap(l => l.replaceAll(" ","").split("\\|"))
val rds = rdd2.toDS`

`val df = spark.read.csv(rds)`

`df.show(false)
+----+---------------+-----+
|_c0 |_c1            |_c2  |
+----+---------------+-----+
|FWD |13032009:09:01 |10.56|
|FWD |13032009:10:53 |11.23|
|FWD |13032009:15:40 |23.20|
|SPOT|13032009:09:04 |11.56|
|FWD |13032009:11:45 |11.23|
|SPOT|13032009:12:30 |23.20|
|FWD |13032009:08:01 |10.56|
|SPOT|13032009:12:30 |11.23|
|FWD |13032009:13:20 |23.20|
|FWD |13032009:14:340|56.00|
|FWD |13032009:08:01 |10.56|
|SPOT|13032009:12:30 |11.23|
|FWD |13032009:13:20 |23.20|
+----+---------------+-----+`